# ui-router navigate to another state onEnter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, wizard

I have a wizard flow A that collects informationA

```
    states["wizard"] = {
        abstract: true,
        url: "^/wizard",
        controller: "wizardController",
        templateUrl: "wizard.html"
    };

    states["wizard.input"] = {
        url: "^/input",
        views: {
            "": {
                controller: "wizardController",
                templateUrl: "form.html"
            }
        }
    }
    states["wizard.completed"] = {
        templateUrl: "completed.html"
    };
```

And another wizard flow B that's the similar structure that's collecting informationB.

What I want to do is when the user navigates to /wizard, it checks if informationB is filled, if not, navigate to fill informationB first and then navigate back to /wizard to continue the wizardA.

What's the best way to do the redirection when the user navigates to /wizard and the best way to return to /wizard when wizardB finishes?

For the return I could pass some param in the url and in the wizardB controller check to see if it needs to go to wizardA, but couldn't quite figure out how to do the first redirect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can use `resolve` (see docs) and check with a service to see if whatever data is needed is there or not and if not return $state.go()

Comment: Thanks charlietfl! Actually my both controller are already injected with same data service, I could just use that!

Comment: Right but you can also intercept within the resolve and controller won't fire at all if you reject the resolve in routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks charlietfl for the information, use resolve to process redirect looks good! Here's how I end up doing:

```
var redirect = (returnState: string) => {
        return ['$q', '$timeout', '$state', 'dataModel', ($q, $timeout, $state, dataModel) => {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $timeout(() => {
                    if (dataModel.informationB === "") {
                        $state.go('wizardB.input', { rs: returnState });
                        deferred.reject();
                    } else {
                        // everything is fine, proceed
                        deferred.resolve();
                    }
                });

                return deferred.promise;
            }
        ];
    }
```

and in the state config:

```
    resolve: {
            redirect: redirect("wizardA.input")
        }
```